# How to share image with facebook "share dialog" among others

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a website which is a test and, based on the result on the test, I want to share a specific image through facebook.
The problem is that all the results are on the same page, which will show to the user only the one that matches his answers.

I know that I have to use the following og code to set an image as thumbmail for the sharer:

```
<meta property="og:image"            content="http://food.png">
```

The problem is, how can i select the image that matches the user's result?
This is a part of my code:

```
var superman = new insieme(all0, imm[0], des0, desc0, pg0);  \\The imm[i] contains the image relative to each result
var darth_vader = new insieme(all1, imm[1], des1, desc1, pg1);
var jorah_mormont = new insieme(all2, imm[2], des2, desc2, pg2);
var spiderman = new insieme(all3, imm[3], des3, desc3, pg3);
var voldemort = new insieme(all4, imm[4], des4, desc4, pg4);
var vendetta = new insieme(all5, imm[5], des5, desc5, pg5);
var sparrow = new insieme(all6, imm[6], des6, desc6, pg6);
var joker = new insieme(all7, imm[7], des7, desc7, pg7);

var pg = new Array(spiderman, superman, jorah_mormont, darth_vader, voldemort, joker, sparrow, vendetta);  <-- This is the array that contains the results' objects
```

In order to access the user's result i use a php variable called $res->random (It's a SQL result which contains different attributes).

It's use is like this:

```
document.write("<h3>" + pg[<?php echo $res->Random; ?>].allineamento + "</h3>");
document.write("<h4>" + pg[<?php echo $res->Random; ?>].personaggio + "</h4>");
document.write(pg[<?php echo $res->Random; ?>].immagine); <-- Here it shows the image that matches the user's result
. . .
```

Here i ask for you help, how can i set a different image for the sharing based on the result? And, while we're at this, how can i set different titles through the following code?

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title_here" />
```

Thanks in advance for the help!